# Getting data through jQuery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm using the following code to get the dataa from the server:

```
  $.getJSON('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/SampleWebService/Service.svc/SampleMethod?callback=?', dd, function (data) {
                alert(data);
  });
```

From the server, I'm sending the byte array as response.
In `firebug`, in `Net > Response` tab, I get:

```
jQuery19101878696953793153_1365677709012([67,37,94,38,42,44,69,67,71,32,97,116,116,97,99,104,101,100,32,102,111,114,32,112,97,116]);
```

Also in `Net > JSON` tab, I get data with several keys.

But how to get the data at `alert(data);`; so that I process on that data.
I don't know, how this thing works.

Edit:

I tried this different approach:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType: "application/javascript",
                data: dd,
                crossDomain: true,
                url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/SampleWebService/Service.svc/SampleMethod",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.parse(data));
                },
                complete: function (request, textStatus) { //for additional info
                    alert(request.responseText);
                    alert(textStatus);
                },
                error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                  }
            });
```

But I got: `parseerror` as alert.

Comment: `data` is that array, isn't it (what do you get from the alert)? Just use it.

Comment: @Bergi, the problem is I don't get any alert.

Comment: Hm. Do you get an error? Append `.fail(alert.bind(window));`, or `console.log` the object that `$.getJSON` returns.

Comment: @Bergi, No. Please see the update.

Comment: @Bergi, also if the received data is less, then it enters `success` section. But for large data, it gives `parseerror`.

Comment: Check your network tab whether the large response is complete. I've heard of cases where the server (or something in the communication channel) chops of very long responses. And if it's complete, maybe it really is invalid; let your debugger halt on scripting errors or post the response into a linter. Btw: You don't need `JSON.parse` with JSONP, as your callback gets passed an object literal not a JSON-string-literal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the data was very huge. I was sending array of around 10,00,000+ bytes.
So instead I divided it into list of bytes (each having 1000 bytes) & then sent as response.

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it solved my problem.
BTW, thanks to all for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the docs (I haven't tried this) you need to explicitly tell jQuery that you're making a JSONP call that will invoke the function that's returned. Something like this:-

```
 $.ajax({
     type : "GET",
     dataType : "jsonp",
     url : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/SampleWebService/Service.svc/SampleMethod",
     success: function(data){
           alert(data);
     }
});
```

Comment: @Bergi - What do you mean 'no'? It looks like mike44 took my suggestion on board and added it to his code and now he's getting a different error.

Comment: I mean that the docs mention that by adding `callback=?` to the URL jQuery will automatically switch to jsonp.

Comment: @Bergi - I didn't know that, but either way, it's worth taking the time to provide information instead of just saying 'no', don't you think?

Comment: I didn't only say "no", I did link it to that part of the docs :-)

Comment: @Bergi - whoops, so you did. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

Function you are looking for is JSON.parse. Please try this code :

```
$.post("YouURL", { 'ParameterName': paramvalue }, function (Data) {
  var data = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: No. a) he uses JSONP b) jQuery would do that for him

Answer (score 0):

Your response is a function call. If u define function name with name jQuery19101878696953793153_1365677709012 you can process the 'data' else from your server just send the json as a response to $.getJSON's callback to work

Comment: No. The point of using `$.ajax` is that jQuery defines that function for you.